# how to change dota 2 Icon?

Tags: icons

I'm new in using ubuntu, I just started 2 days ago. I've installed steam which worked perfectly but the only thing is when I installed dota 2, the Icon isn't correct it only shows me this one[here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTlF8.png)
Is there any way to fix this? 
if so can you help me?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will work on Ubuntu, but it worked for me on elementary OS
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2870/change-specified-apps-icon/2913#2913